# Not validating file, a security issue?

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I'm just reading [this documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php) and came across the following sentence: **"Not validating which file you operate on may mean that users can access sensitive information in other directories."**

First of all, it doesn't explain what constitutes "validating" in this context, so I was hoping somebody would be able to clarify this for me.

Lastly, how exactly would users be able to access other directories if one didn't "validate" the file they're operating on?

Answer (score 1):

It means if you don't validate the file which is uploaded, you *potentially* open yourself up to someone simply uploading a PHP script.

Depending on whether you place that file in an accessible location in your webroot, will determine whether the user/attacker can run it.

So if you expect images, check its an image. If you expect .xml check its an xml file.

The second part of your question, it's trivial to traverse the filesystem once you have a backdoor.